# Cutsomize rofi when using SLiM

Tags: arch-linux, i3

I wan't to customize rofi, if I am right rofi's configarution should be put in .Xresources file, but SLiM login manager seems not to load this file. Where should I put the code ?

I am using archlinux with i3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your `~/.xinitrc` somewhere before the line where you call your wm (i3 in your case).

```
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```